# Enviar arquivo e texto via jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Pessoal eu consegui enviar o arquivo por esse código:

```
var jqXHRData = null;
        $(function () {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
            $("#divUpload").on('click', function () {
                $('#fu-my-simple-upload').click();
            });

            $("#hl-start-upload").on('click', function () {
                if (jqXHRData != null) {
                    if (jqXHRData) {
                        jqXHRData.submit();
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Selecione o arquivo, antes de enviar!", "Mensagem do Sistema");
                }
            });

            $("#fu-my-simple-upload").on('change', function () {
                $("#tbx-file-path").val(this.files[0].name); 
            });

            'use strict';

            $('#fu-my-simple-upload').fileupload({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("IDetailsArchives", "IMaterial")',
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                    jqXHRData = data
            },
            done: function (event, data) {
                if (data.result.isUploaded) {
                    $("#tbx-file-path").val("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado...");
                    toastr.success(data.result.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                }
                else {

                }
                jqXHRData = null;
                var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
            },
            fail: function (event, data) {
                if (data.files[0].error) {
                    toastr.error(data.files[0].error, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                    var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                }
                jqXHRData = null;
            }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress').progress({
                    percent: progress
                })
            });
        });

        function progresso() {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
        };
```

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult IDetailsArchives(IArquivoMetadado arq)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files["MyFile"];
            bool isUploaded = false;
            string message = "Arquivo não enviado";

            if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength != 0)
            {
                string pathForSaving = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Arquivos");
                if (this.CreateFolderIfNeeded(pathForSaving))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string FileNameNew = CriarNome(myFile.FileName, arq.conteudoID, arq.conteudoNome);
                        myFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathForSaving, myFile.FileName));
                        isUploaded = true;
                        message = "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        message = string.Format("Arquivo não enviado: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new { isUploaded = isUploaded, message = message }, "text/html");
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="ui grid">
<div class="fifteen wide column centered">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="six wide column">
            <div class="ui fluid basic segment">
                <h4>Selecione o Arquivo: </h4>
                <div class="ui fluid action input">
                    <input type="hidden" id="conteudoID" name="conteudoID" value="@ViewBag.ID" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="conteudoNome" name="conteudoNome" value="@ViewBag.Nome" />
                    <input type="text" id="tbx-file-path" value="Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado..." readonly="readonly" />                        
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file" , style = "display: none", accept = ".jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" })
                    <div class="ui blue icon button" id="divUpload">
                        <i class="folder open outline icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <a id="hl-start-upload" class="ui right labeled blue icon button">
                    <i class="cloud upload icon"></i>
                    Enviar Arquivo
                </a>
                <div class="ui green progress">
                    <div class="bar">
                        <div class="progress"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4>
                    Regras de Envio:<br />
                    • São aceitos somente os arquivos do formato: JPG, PNG, PDF, DOC e DOCX <br />
                    • A barra acima mostrar o progresso de envio do arquivo ao servidor.
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ten wide column">
            <div class="fifteen wide column centered">
                @Html.Action("IDetailsArchivesLista", "IMaterial", new { id = ViewBag.IDConteudo })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

mas como envio outros valores junto com o meu arquivo? Tipo id, nome e o arquivo? Os inputs de id e nome estarão hidden

**Atualização 1**
JS Code:

```
var jqXHRData = null;
        $(function () {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
            $("#divUpload").on('click', function () {
                $('#MyFile').click();
            });

            $("#hl-start-upload").on('click', function () {
                if (jqXHRData != null) {
                    if (jqXHRData) {
                        $("#fileupload").submit();
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Selecione o arquivo, antes de enviar!", "Mensagem do Sistema");
                }
            });

            $("#MyFile").on('change', function () {
                $("#tbx-file-path").val(this.files[0].name); 
            });

            'use strict';

            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("IMaterial","IDetailsArchives")',
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                    jqXHRData = data
            },
            done: function (event, data) {
                if (data.result.isUploaded) {
                    $("#tbx-file-path").val("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado...");
                    toastr.success(data.result.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                }
                else {

                }
                jqXHRData = null;
                var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
            },
            fail: function (event, data) {
                if (data.files[0].error) {
                    toastr.error(data.files[0].error, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                    var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                }
                jqXHRData = null;
            }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress').progress({
                    percent: progress
                })
            });
        });

        function progresso() {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que você está complicando demais algo simples.

Basta criar um **form** e enviar os dados por **Ajax**. Um exemplo seria assim:

**Model**

```
public class IArquivoMetadado
    {
        public string conteudoID { get; set; }
        public string conteudoNome { get; set; }
        public string caminhoArquivo { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@model jQueryUpload.Models.IArquivoMetadado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IDetailsArchives";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("IDetailsArchives", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "form-id" }))
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET Web API - File Upload</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size:medium">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Archivo:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoID" name="conteudoID" value="2" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoNome" name="conteudoNome" value="3" />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file", accept = ".jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subir" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}



@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#form-id").submit(function () {

            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.pathname,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>

}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IDetailsArchives(IArquivoMetadado arq)
        {
            bool isUploaded = false;
            string message = "Arquivo não enviado";

            if (arq.MyFile != null && arq.MyFile.ContentLength != 0)
            {
                string pathForSaving = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Arquivos");
                if (this.CreateFolderIfNeeded(pathForSaving))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string FileNameNew = CriarNome(arq.MyFile.FileName, arq.conteudoID, arq.conteudoNome);
                        arq.MyFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathForSaving, arq.MyFile.FileName));
                        isUploaded = true;
                        message = "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        message = string.Format("Arquivo não enviado: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new { isUploaded = isUploaded, message = message }, "text/html");
        }
```

Apenas alterei seu código com o intuito de deixar o mais simples possível.

A maior diferença é que estou utilizando o [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData), que em resumo ele  usa o mesmo formato que um form utilizaria se o tipo de codificação estivesse configurado como "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Aconselho olhar como está o código, e adaptá-lo na resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, pois creio que irá querer adicionar a barra de progresso e outras informações.

Comment: Poderia dar uma explicação, eu pessoalmente entendi, você usou o FormData, mas acho que seria interessante torna-lo mais evidente ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento As vezes fazemos algo tão natural que acabamos nos esquecendo. Valeu por lembrar. :p

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a documentação do https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ o uso básico é isto:

Html:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="exemplo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

Javascript:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
...
```

Ou seja o `$('#fileupload').fileupload` aponta para o `<FORM>`, mas no caso você apontou para o:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file" , style = "display: none", accept = ".jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" })
```

Que gera:

```
<input id="fu-my-simple-upload" type="file" />
```

O correto é criar um FORM e jogar tudo dentro dele (se já não existir) e trocar o ID de apontamento, faça algo como:

```
<div class="ui fluid action input">
    <form id="MEU_FORM" action="[URL DE DESTINO, EDITE AQUI]" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoID" name="conteudoID" value="@ViewBag.ID" />
        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoNome" name="conteudoNome" value="@ViewBag.Nome" />
        <input type="text" id="tbx-file-path" value="Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado..." readonly="readonly" />                        
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file" , style = "display: none", accept = ".jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" })
        <div class="ui blue icon button" id="divUpload">
            <i class="folder open outline icon"></i>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

E o Javascript:

```
$('#MEU_FORM').fileupload({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("IMaterial","IDetailsArchives")',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
                jqXHRData = data
        },
```

Comment: Certo, mas no caso eu vou ter que inserir a action ali no form e a url que eu passo no fileupload o que eu faço com ela?

Comment: @DeividFarias o endereço de destino do upload. Eu acho que é este `@Url.Action("IDetailsArchives", "IMaterial")`

Answer (score 0):

No final ficou da seguinte forma:
Utilizei o que o @Randrade me passou, mas incrementei para poder funcionar a progress bar.

Estava utilizando o Jquery File Upload, mas não estava conseguindo enviar os dois inputs que estavam ocultos, então retirei o Jquery File Upload e utilizei o Ajax para poder enviar o formulário.

O usuário @GuilhermeNascimento tentou me ajudar com o Jquery File Upload, mas mesmo tentando da forma que ele colocou não cheguei ao resultado positivo, que era enviar o arquivo e o texto no mesmo formulário.

Assim alterei no meu JS isso :

```
'use strict';

        $('#fu-my-simple-upload').fileupload({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("IDetailsArchives", "IMaterial")',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
                jqXHRData = data
        },
        done: function (event, data) {
            if (data.result.isUploaded) {
                $("#tbx-file-path").val("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado...");
                toastr.success(data.result.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
            }
            else {

            }
            jqXHRData = null;
            var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
        },
        fail: function (event, data) {
            if (data.files[0].error) {
                toastr.error(data.files[0].error, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
            }
            jqXHRData = null;
        }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: progress
            })
        });
```

por isso:

```
$("#form-id").submit(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("IDetailsArchives","IMaterial")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tbx-file-path").val("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado...");
                    toastr.success(data.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                    var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    toastr.error(data.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                        var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) {
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', showProgress, false);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Uploadress is not supported.");
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

**Lembrando** que arquivos pequenos não afetaram a porcentagem do progress bar, ou seja, vai a 100% com facilidade.

Segue todo o código funcional:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult IDetailsArchives(IArquivoMetadado arq)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files["MyFile"];
            bool isUploaded = false;
            string message = "Arquivo não enviado";

            if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength != 0)
            {
                string pathForSaving = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Arquivos");
                if (this.CreateFolderIfNeeded(pathForSaving))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string arquivoAtual = myFile.FileName.Split('.').First();
                        string tipoAtual = myFile.FileName.Split('.').Last();
                        string FileNameNew = CriarNome(arquivoAtual, arq.conteudoNome, arq.conteudoID, tipoAtual);
                        myFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathForSaving, FileNameNew));
                        isUploaded = true;
                        message = "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        message = string.Format("Arquivo não enviado: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new { message = message }, "text/html");
        }

        private bool CreateFolderIfNeeded(string path)
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    /*TODO: You must process this exception.*/
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private string CriarNome(string nomeAtual, string conteudoNome, string idcont, string tipo)
        {
            string data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
            novoNome = "" + conteudoNome + "-" + nomeAtual + "-" + idcont + "-" + data + "."+tipo;
            return novoNome;
        }
```

**HTML/JS :**

```
@section Scripts{
       
        var jqXHRData = null;
        $(function () {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
            $("#divUpload").on('click', function () {
                $('#MyFile').click();
            });

            $("#hl-start-upload").on('click', function () {
                var arquivo = $("#MyFile").val();
                if (arquivo == "") {
                    toastr.error("Selecione o arquivo, antes de enviar!", "Mensagem do Sistema");
                }
                else
                    $("#form-id").submit();
            });

            $("#MyFile").on('change', function () {
                $("#tbx-file-path").val(this.files[0].name); 
            });

            $("#form-id").submit(function () {
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("IDetailsArchives","IMaterial")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#tbx-file-path").val("Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado...");
                        toastr.success(data.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                        var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        toastr.error(data.message, "Mensagem do Sistema");
                            var intervalo = window.setInterval(progresso, 3000);
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    xhr: function () {
                        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if (myXhr.upload) {
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', showProgress, false);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Uploadress is not supported.");
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });

           function showProgress(evt) {
               if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                   var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                   $('.progress').progress({
                       percent: percentComplete
                   })
               }
           }

        function progresso() {
            $('.progress').progress({
                percent: 0
            });
        };
    
}
```

```
<div class="ui grid">
<div class="fifteen wide column centered">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="six wide column">
            <div class="ui fluid basic segment">
                <h4>Selecione o Arquivo: </h4>
                <div class="ui fluid action input">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("IDetailsArchives", "IMaterial", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "form-id" }))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoID" name="conteudoID" value="@ViewBag.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="conteudoNome" name="conteudoNome" value="@ViewBag.Nome" />
                        <input type="text" id="tbx-file-path" value="Nenhum Arquivo Selecionado..." readonly="readonly" />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "MyFile", type = "file", style = "display: none", accept = ".jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx" })
                        <div class="ui blue icon button" id="divUpload">
                            <i class="folder open outline icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <br />
                <a id="hl-start-upload" class="ui right labeled blue icon button">
                    <i class="cloud upload icon"></i>
                    Enviar Arquivo
                </a>
                <div class="ui green progress">
                    <div class="bar">
                        <div class="progress"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4>
                    Regras de Envio:<br />
                    • São aceitos somente os arquivos do formato: JPG, PNG, PDF, DOC e DOCX <br />
                    • A barra acima mostrar o progresso de envio do arquivo ao servidor.
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ten wide column">
            <div class="fifteen wide column centered">
                @Html.Action("IDetailsArchivesLista", "IMaterial", new { id = ViewBag.IDConteudo })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que estava de errado e o que teve que fazer pra funcionar, torne a resposta relevante pra futuros visitantes que possam ter o mesmo tipo de dificuldade ;)